# DataBindings Delete button

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, bindingnavigator

I created a form in which I have 4 textboxes and the out of the box bindingnavigator. I am displaying data from a single table and I would like to make the delete button work... and I can't. 
Here is the method I am using to refresh/add the data from the db to my bindingsource and data source (which I am calling the in the load of the form):

```
public void Fill_DataSource()
      {

          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRDBConnection"].ConnectionString);
          try
          {
              conn.Open();
              SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("select * from BusinessGroups", conn));
              DataSet ds = new DataSet();
              da1.Fill(ds);
              BGbindSource.ResetBindings(false);
              BGbindSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
              bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BGbindSource;

              //BusinessGroupCode
              textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
              textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.BGbindSource, "BusinessGroupCode", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

              //BusinessGroupName
              textBox2.DataBindings.Clear();
              textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.BGbindSource, "BusinessGroupName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

              //BusinessGroupDesc
              textBox3.DataBindings.Clear();
              textBox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.BGbindSource, "BusinessGroupDescription", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

              //BusinessGroupId
              textBox4.DataBindings.Clear();
              textBox4.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.BGbindSource, "BGId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
              toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Database Is Offline or the Connection is not set correctly!";
          }
          finally
          {
              conn.Close();
          }
      }
```

And here is the code behind the delete button:

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRDBConnection"].ConnectionString);

          try
          {
              conn.Open();
              SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("delete from BusinessGroups where BGId=@BGId",conn);

              //BGId
              SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@BGId", SqlDbType.Int);
              if (textBox4.Text.Trim() == "")
              {
                  param4.Value = -999;
              }
              else
              {
                  param4.Value = textBox4.Text;
              }
              sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param4);

              try
              {
                  sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  //MessageBox.Show("Successfully deleted!");
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error! Could not delete the requested information!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              }
              //Fill_DataSource();
              BGbindSource.ResetBindings(true);


          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error! Could not delete the requested information!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              //throw;
          }
          finally
          {
              if (conn != null) conn.Close();
          }
      }
```

If I press it, it will delete the previous item in my binding, to be more accurate, using breakpoints, I noticed that the BGId paramater always takes the value of the previous BGId, I mean not the one that I am currently positioned on, but the previous one. Why is this happening and how can I solve it? 
Thanks a lot!
Edited: To respond to your questions, here is the code behind the save button who does works as expected:

```
private void bindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (BGbindSource.Current == null) return;

          if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "")
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Business Group Code cannot be blank!");
              textBox1.Focus();
              return;
          }

          if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == "")
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Business Group Name cannot be blank!");
              textBox2.Focus();
              return;
          }

          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRDBConnection"].ConnectionString);
          try
          {
              conn.Open();
              SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("if exists (select 1 from BusinessGroups where BGId=@BGId) "
                  + " update BusinessGroups "
                  + " set BusinessGroupCode=@BGCode, "
                  + " BusinessGroupName=@BGName, "
                  + " BusinessGroupDescription=@BGDesc, "
                  + " UpdateTimeStamp= getdate()"
                  + " where BGId=@BGId "
                  + " else "
                  + " insert into BusinessGroups (BusinessGroupCode,BusinessGroupName,BusinessGroupDescription) "
                  + " select @BGCode,@BGName,@BGDesc " 
                  , conn);
              //BGCode
              SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@BGCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30 );
              param1.Value = textBox1.Text;
              sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

              //BGName
              SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@BGName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150);
              param2.Value = textBox2.Text;
              sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

              //BGDesc
              SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@BGDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000);
              param3.Value = textBox3.Text;
              sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

              //BGId
              SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@BGId", SqlDbType.Int);
              if (textBox4.Text.Trim() == "")
              {
                  param4.Value = -999;
              }
              else 
              {
                  param4.Value = textBox4.Text;
              }
              sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param4);

              sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              Fill_DataSource();
              //BGbindSource.ResetBindings(false);

              MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved!");

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error! Could not save the requested information!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              throw;
          }
          finally
          {
              if (conn != null)  conn.Close();
          }
      }
```

Comment: The simples would be just to add 1 to your ID right? Also I would recommend you to set the bindings in XAML.

Comment: It would be, if BGId is always sequential... but is it?

Comment: @Tafari how could he know? because he's not the OP :)))

Comment: @Tafari it doesn't matter that but it does matter that the OP may not be notified by your comment instead `Timothy` will be.

Comment: When debugging, what's the `Text` of the `textbox4`, I'm pretty sure that you will see the correct value of `textbox4.Text` when you navigate through the rows.

Comment: @Sergiu do your **TextBox** es show values of correct item?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the questions and interest in my post. I edited the initial description, adding the code behind the save button that does work. For that, the textboxes do pass the correct parameters .. the ones that I am currently positioned on. Please help :( And to answer your questions, the BGid is an identity field and if I start deleting values and then add new ones, I can no longer expect to have incremental data for that column.

Comment: I added this as the first line in the code of the delete button:string test = textBox4.Text; and added it into the watch. If I am on let's say BGid=3 in the form, when I press the delete button, in the debug's watch the BGIds value is 2... I don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

To delete row using the **default delete button** on the `BindingNavigator`, you don't need any code. So just remove your own code in `bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click` and it should work.

Comment: I did that but it will only delete the record from the form, not the database.

Comment: @Sergiu do you use any `DataAdapter` in your project?

Comment: Yup, it's in the Fill_dataSource method at the begining of the post.

Comment: @Sergiu if so just call the `Update` method with the underlying `DataTable` passed in to update.

Comment: Do I have to declare the data adapter and the data set once again? Ok, given that I am new could you please send me the code? Thank you so much for your interest and help!

Comment: I finally solved it by deleting the out of the box delete button from the DataNavigator and created my own.